# How can I determine the attribute data type of an entity in Core Data?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa, core-data

In Core Data I have an entity called `item` which has the the attribute `score`.

Currently `score` has the type `int16_t`.

`score`s value is updated from different places within the project, by parsing it via `[[UITextField text] integerValue]`, while keeping an open eye for overflow.

`score`s datatype is very likely to change in the future.
I want to minimise future risk associated with that change.

The only way I can think of is by the preprocessor macro `#define itemScore_t int16_t`.

Is there a better way, such as determining the datatype directly from Core Data?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `NSEntityDescription` you can navigate to the particular attribute and get the `NSAttributeDescription`, from there you can get the `attributeType` (which gives `NSInteger16AttributeType` / `NSInteger32AttributeType` / `NSInteger64AttributeType`).